# Soma de tempo trabalhado de vários colaboradores

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma tabela colaboradores, e outras 2 tabelas de atividades, cada uma com uma coluna de tempo usado para realizar aquela atividade e gostaria de somar essas tabelas para saber o tempo total, exemplo, o funcionário A fez 10 horas em um projeto (tabela 1) e outras 10 horas em atividades paralelas (tabela 2), soma as duas e fica 20 horas.

Estou usando Laravel, a minha dúvida é como fazer isso usando o Eloquent ORM. Estou um pouco preso na lógica, preciso usar relação many to many? vocês tem algum exemplo? Desde já agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Opa Carlos!? Posta a estrutura das tabelas que você quer fazer o relacionamento. Desta forma a galera terá maior visão para poder te ajudar

Comment: Pronto Walmir, não é exatamente igual o nome dos campos, mas a estrutura é a mesma.

Comment: Você está querendo somar tempo_atv_proj com tempo_atv_ext de um determinado coladorador_id? você criou as classes Eloquent?

Comment: Isso Virgilio, quero somar essas colunas de tempo, criei somente as models de cada haha, nada além disso.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoSilva se pode colocar esses `models`?